# php & mysql create join query

Tags: php, mysql, left-join

I'm trying to create a join query.  I am busy with a quiz site and I am trying to display a list of all the tests the user are NOT linked to.

**Table1** (This table contains a list of all the available tests)

id = int

test_name = varchar

*example:*

1, Test1

2, Test2

3, Test3

**Table2** (This table contains the userid and testid which the user is already linked to)

id = int

id_usrs = int

id_test = int

*example:*
1, 1, 1

2, 1, 2

**So basically if my query works then from table2 just Test3 should show up on my result.**

**Query:**

```
$sql0 = "SELECT table1.* FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id_test WHERE table2.id_usrs = '$userid2' AND table2.id_test Is Null ";
$result0 = mysql_query($sql0);
while($row0 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result0)) {

 $test_name=$row['test_name'];
echo $test_name;
}
```

***The question:***  I need to display the the result from table2 which is not in table1

Comment: I see no question here. State a question :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be your query

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
WHERE table1.`id` NOT IN 
       (SELECT table1.`id` 
        FROM table1 
           JOIN table2 
           ON table1.id = table2.id_test 
        WHERE table2.id_usrs = 1);
```